# Why is my http server printing out the same bytes? (C)

Tags: c, http, server

I have just started an assignment in which I must create a simple server that processes http requests.

To get me started, I decided to make a basic server that waits for a connection and then continuously prints out whatever it receives from read().

Using this code to print, I expected to see a plain text http request with \r and \n replaced by `<\r>` and `<\n>` respectively (when I visit http://ip:port in my web browser):

```
    char buffer[buffer_size];
    size_t bytes;

    while ((bytes = read(s, buffer, buffer_size - 1)) > 0) {
      buffer[bytes] = '\0';
      int i = 0;
      while(buffer[i] != '\0') {
        if (buffer[i] == '\n') {
          printf("%s","<\\n>\n");
        } else if (buffer[i] == '\r') {
          printf("%s","<\\r>");
        } else {
          printf("%c",buffer[i]);
        }
        i++;
      }
    }
```

However, instead I just get my console spammed with alternating `<\r>` and some weird square with what looks like 001B written inside (Here is a link to a picture of my terminal http://gyazo.com/13288989dc0c1f4782052a1914eb7f84). Is this a problem with my code? Does Mozilla keep spamming these intentionally?

EDIT:All of my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

#define buffer_size 1024


int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  int port;
  int client;
  struct sockaddr_in6 my_add;
  struct sockaddr_in6 their_add;
  socklen_t their_add_size = sizeof(their_add);

  if (argc != 2) {
    printf("%s\n","Usage: ./server <port>");
    return -1;
  }

  port = atoi(argv[1]);

  my_add.sin6_family = AF_INET6;
  my_add.sin6_addr = in6addr_any;
  my_add.sin6_port = htons(port);

  int s = socket(PF_INET6, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

  if (s < 0) {
    printf("%s","error on socket()");
    return -1;
  }

  if (bind (s, (struct sockaddr *) &my_add, sizeof(my_add)) != 0) {
    printf("%s","error on bind()");
    return -1;
  }

  if (listen (s, 5) != 0) {
    printf("%s","error on listen()");
    return -1;
  }

  client = accept(s, (struct sockaddr *) &their_add, &their_add_size);
  printf("%s","connected");

  char buffer[buffer_size];
  size_t bytes;

  while ((bytes = read(s, buffer, buffer_size - 1)) > 0) {
    buffer[bytes] = '\0';
    int i = 0;
    while(buffer[i] != '\0') {
      if (buffer[i] == '\n') {
    printf("%s","<\\n>\n");
      } else if (buffer[i] == '\r') {
    printf("%s","<\\r>");
      } else {
    printf("%c",buffer[i]);
      }
      i++;
    }
  }

  if (bytes != 0) {
    printf("%s","something went wrong. bytes != 0.");
    return -1;
  }

  printf("%s", "connection closed");
  close(s);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: what does the debugger show is in buffer?

Comment: @pm100 sorry I'm not sure what you mean? I'm just using emacs basically as a text editor and compiling in terminal

Comment: you should learn how to run your program under a debugger. ON linux that will be gdb, you can pause the program inspect data, etc. google 'getting started with gdb'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using the wrong data type for the `bytes` variable:

The function prototype of `read()` is:

`ssize_t read(int, void *, size_t)`

But you are using `size_t` which is unsigned (`ssize_t` is **signed**)

So if `read()` ever returns a negative number it gets converted to a huge number effectively causing an infinite loop.

Also you can simplify your code:

```c
char buffer[buffer_size];
ssize_t bytes;

while ((bytes = read(s, buffer, buffer_size - 1)) > 0) {
    // Just loop over the number of bytes we've just read
    for (ssize_t i = 0; i < bytes; ++i) {
        const char ch = buffer[i];

        // Handle `ch`
        if (ch == '\n') {
            printf("<\\n>\n");
        } else if (ch == '\r') {
            printf("<\\r>");
        } else {
            printf("%c", ch);
        }
    }
}
```

**Regarding updated OP question:**

```c
if (bytes != 0) {
    printf("%s","something went wrong. bytes != 0.");
    return -1;
}
```

Should be:

```c
if (0 > bytes) {
    printf("bytes is negative. ERRNO = %d", errno);

    return -1;
}
```

(Include `#include <errno.h>` for it to exist.)

Running your code on my machine gives me `57` which is `Socket not connected` so you have another error in your logic.

**A quick search on google reveals the problem:**

> You're sending to the listening socket, when you should be sending to
>   the accepted/connected one.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22127669/2005038)

So instead of:

```c
while ((bytes = read(s, buffer, buffer_size - 1)) > 0) {
```

You should be using:

```c
while ((bytes = read(client, buffer, buffer_size - 1)) > 0) {
```

Because you want to read from the connected client `client`, not your listening socket `s`.

This fixes the problem on my machine:

```c
./a.out 1337
connectedGET / HTTP/1.1<\r><\n>
Host: localhost:1337<\r><\n>
Connection: keep-alive<\r><\n>
Cache-Control: max-age=0<\r><\n>
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36<\r><\n>
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1<\r><\n>
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8<\r><\n>
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br<\r><\n>
Accept-Language: de-DE,de;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4<\r><\n>
Cookie: TripmanagerHighlightedParameter_index=flow_l_h<\r><\n>
<\r><\n>
```

Comment: I just changed my code and now when I try,  I instead exit the while loop without printing anything and my next check fails (bytes != 0)

Comment: Wow looks like I got the client variable ready and then forgot to use it. I'm extremely grateful for the time you put in to help me solve this. All is working well now.

Comment: @toastedDeli You're welcome :) I'm glad I could help.